# How can remove blank form lines on submit using javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form with input text fields. If 1 or more lines are left blank I want all the text to move up and fill in the blank lines.

Example:
There are 6 input boxes. Lines 3 & 5 are left blank.

```
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text" name="itemLine_1_1">
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text" name="itemLine_1_2">
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="" name="itemLine_1_3">
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text" name="itemLine_1_4">
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="" name="itemLine_1_5">
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text" name="itemLine_1_6">
```

But when the form is submitted the info will come over like this. The 2 blank lines move up and the last 2 lines are now empty.

```
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text" name="itemLine_1_1">
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text" name="itemLine_1_2">
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text" name="itemLine_1_3">
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text" name="itemLine_1_4">
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="" name="itemLine_1_5">
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="" name="itemLine_1_6">
```

Comment: Why are you doing this on the client? Seems to me it's more appropriate to deal with it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is your code http://jsfiddle.net/qXWgZ/3/

HTML

```
<form name="frmLines" id="frmLines">
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text" name="itemLine_1_1"><br>
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text" name="itemLine_1_2"><br>
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="" name="itemLine_1_3"><br>
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text" name="itemLine_1_4"><br>
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="" name="itemLine_1_5"><br>
<input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text" name="itemLine_1_6"><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#frmLines").submit(function(){
 // list of inputs
 var inputs = $("input[type=text]");
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   var input = $(inputs[i]);
   // ignore not empty input or there is no more input left
   if (input.val() != "" || i >= inputs.length - 1)
     continue;
   // looking for next not empty input
   for (var j = i + 1; j < inputs.length; j++) {
     var nextInput = $(inputs[j]);
     // ignore empty input
     if (nextInput.val() == "")
       continue;
     // fullfill last input by next not empty input
     input.val(nextInput.val());
     // make next input as empty
     nextInput.val("");
     // break out of looking
     break;
   }
 }
 return false; // return true for production
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple code.
http://jsfiddle.net/HxK4F/1/

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var els = $('input[type=text]');
    for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++)
    {
        if (els.eq(i).val()=='')
        {
            for(var j=i; j<els.length-1; j++)
                els.eq(j).val(els.eq(j+1).val());
            els.eq(els.length-1).val('');
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

And pure JS solution
http://jsfiddle.net/9Ng4d/4/

```
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function(){
    var el = this.getElementsByTagName('input'), els = [];
    for(var i=0; i<el.length; i++)
        if (el[i].type == 'text') els.push(el[i]); // remove non text elements

    for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++)
    {
        if (els[i].value=='')
        {
            for(var j=i; j<els.length-1; j++)
                 els[j].value = els[j+1].value;
            els[els.length-1].value = '';
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't actually need the lines to rearrange themselves, seeing as nobody would actually see it because the page submits. So the easiest thing to do is just assign the names dynamically on submit.

HTML:

```
<form name="frmLines" id="frmLines">
    <input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text"><br>
    <input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text"><br>
    <input type="text" tabindex="2"  value=""><br>
    <input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text"><br>
    <input type="text" tabindex="2"  value=""><br>
    <input type="text" tabindex="2"  value="Some Text"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#frmLines").submit(function(){
    var count = 1;
    var assign_names = function() {
        $(this).attr('name', 'itemLine_1_' + count);
        count++;
    };
    $(this).find('input[type="text"][value!=""]').each(assign_names);
    $(this).find('input[type="text"][value=""]').each(assign_names);
});
```

This is much simpler and easier to understand than the other answers.

Comment: `just assign the names dynamically on submit` you will never know why he needs it :) may be he is using AJAX and needs visual replacement of the values too.. Or, for example, name attributes are not so simple and obvious.